# Why does Ruby hash not last method？

Tags: ruby

I solve a problem, it needs to take last key-value pair of a hash. Example:

```rb
hash =  { "aa" => { :count => 1, :width => 333 }, "bb" => { :count => 1, :width => 77 } }
```

I need the result

```rb
result = [ "bb" => { :count => 1, :width => 77 } ]
```

Hash has the first method

```rb
hash.first
=> [ "aa" => { :count => 1, :width => 333 } ]
```

I want to use the `last` method, but an error occurs

```rb
NoMethodError: undefined method `last' for #<Hash:0x00007f82c75a9988>
from (pry):19:in `__pry__'
```

Here's my solution

```rb
result = [hash.stringify_keys.keys[1], hash.stringify_keys.values[1]]
```

My question is why Ruby hash does not have the last method.

Comment: Try `hash.to_a.last`

Comment: A better implementation would be `[ { hash.keys.last => hash[hash.keys.last] } ]`. There are some efficiencies that can be made (not having to call `#keys` more than once), but this will work with a hash of any size.

Comment: Hashes are (theoretically) unordered, although sometimes the underlying implementation is ordered. This is not guaranteed, so it doesn’t make sense to have a Hash#last method.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs: In Ruby, it is specified (I think since Ruby 1.8 or so), that a Hash in maintained in insertion order.

Comment: @user1934428, make that 1.9.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `first` method on ruby hashes comes from [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html). It doesn't have the method `last`, so `Hash` also doesn't have it.

If I were to guess, `Enumerable` doesn't have it for efficiency reasons. Since `Enumerable` only needs the method `each` to work, determining the last element would require full traversal of the sequence (which may be infinitely long).

And `Hash` doesn't have it because a key-value map is, conceptually, not an ordered data structure.

Comment: Ruby has had insertion-ordered Hash since at least 1.9, possibly a little before. I do remember having to implement an `OrderedHash` at one point because Ruby didn’t support the notion of order in Hash. It’s not pathologically unordered the way that Go’s map iterator is (Go’s map iterator has an explicit random selection step before iteration so every starting key is different).

Comment: @AustinZiegler: yes, hashes in ruby happen to maintain insertion order (at least, nowadays). Hence the qualifier "conceptually"

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following hash and array:

```
h = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
a = [:a, :b, :c]
```

As you know it's not possible access Hash by an integer index like an array, but by key, which is the power of the hash data structure.

Accessing by index, is simple to implement a method like [Array#last](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-last) (apart the real implementation and without argument) without transverse the whole array:

```
a[a.size - 1] #=> :c
```

But how can you do with a Hash?

As mentioned by @Sergio Tulentsev [Enumerable#first](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-first) is implemented and [Hash class includes Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html) but there is not Enumerable#last.

So `.first` works:

```
h.first(2) #=> [[:a, 1], [:b, 2]]
h.first(1) #=> [[:a, 1]]
h.first #=> [:a, 1]
```

---

The only way to get the last element is to use some workaround, for example:

```
h.to_a.last #=> [:c, 3]
[h.keys.last, h.values.last] #=> [:c, 3]
```

The [Hash documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html) says:

> A Hash is a dictionary-like collection of unique keys and their values. Also called associative arrays, they are similar to Arrays, but where an Array uses integers as its index, a Hash allows you to use any object type.

**But also that:**

> **Hashes enumerate their values in the order that the corresponding keys were inserted.**

So, I didn't benchmarked, but maybe this is an efficient way?

```
h.reverse_each.first #=> [:c, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

I expect there is no method `Hash#last` because coders (especially old-school coders) rarely make use of the fact that (since Ruby 1.9) key-insertion order is maintained for hashes, and even when they do make use of that property, needing the last key-value pair would be so unusual, yet so easily satisfied (e.g., `h.to_a.last`) that the addition of a method `Hash#last` to the Ruby core would not be warranted.

I can also understand the Ruby monk's reluctance to create an `Enumerable` method `last`. If, for example, `self` were the range `(0..Float::INFINITY)`, it would be converted to an enumerator `(0..Float::INFINITY).each`, resulting in the block being executed forever.

Suppose

```
h = { "aa" => { :count => 1, :width => 333 },
      "bb" => { :count => 1, :width => 77 } }
```

Consider the various ways the last key-value pair could be extracted, either as:

```
["bb", { :count => 1, :width => 77 }]
```

or

```
{ "bb" => { :count => 1, :width => 77 } }
```

I assume an array is desired, but if not the array `a` can be easily converted to a hash having a single key-value pair: `[a].to_h`.

Several possibilities come to mind:

**#1**

```
h.to_a.last
  #=> ["bb", {:count=>1, :width=>77}]
```

This is the simplest. It's only downside is that it creates a temporary array of the key-value pairs of the hash.

**#2**

```
k = h.keys.last
  #=> "bb"
[k, h[k]]
  #=> ["bb", {:count=>1, :width=>77}]
```

This is also quite simple. It's only downside is that it creates a temporary array of the hash's keys. That temporary array, however, is smaller than the temporary array created by #1.

**#3**

```
n = h.size
  #=> 2
h.reject { (n -= 1) > 0 }.first
  #=> ["bb", {:count=>1, :width=>77}]
```

This has the advantage that, while it creates a temporary hash containing a single key, that hash may consume less memory than the temporary arrays created by #1 and #2. See [Hash#reject](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-reject). Note that one can write `h.reject { (n -= 1) > 0 } #=> {"bb"=>{:count=>1, :width=>77}}` if it is desired that the return value be a hash.

**#4**

```
enum = h.to_enum
  #=> #<Enumerator: {"aa"=>{:count=>1, :width=>333},
  #                  "bb"=>{:count=>1, :width=>77}}:each> 
last = nil
loop { last = enum.next }
last
  #=> ["bb", {:count=>1, :width=>77}]
```

This is the only method so far that computes the desired array without constructing a temporary array or hash. Note that after that last element has been generated by `enum` `enum.next` generates a `StopIteration` exception that is handled by [Kernel#loop](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) by breaking the loop.

Now let's consider how a method `Enumerable#last` might be created (recognizing the pitfall I mentioned in my second paragraph).

```
module Enumerable
  def last
    obj = nil
    each { |o| obj = o }
    obj
  end
end
h.last
  #=> ["bb", {:count=>1, :width=>77}]
```

When `last` is called by a hash, the first step (as with all Enumerable methods) is to convert its receiver to an enumerator), by sending it the method `each`, here [Hash#each](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-each).<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1. If `last`'s receiver is already an enumerator, [Enumerator#each](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-each) is sent to the receiver which merely executes the block against `self`.</sup>

Comment: @Stefan proposed #1 in a comment on the question. I cannot, however, say in good conscious that I would not have thought of it had he not done so.

Comment: Your last example can be rewritten as `def last ; obj = nil ; each { |o| obj = o } ; obj ; end`.

Comment: Good suggestion, @Stefan. It clarified my thinking about one point. I had thought `Enumerable` methods sent `each` to its receiver except when the receiver was an enumerator. I'm now thinking `each` is probably sent to enumerators as well because executing `Enumerator#each` on an enumerator is probably as fast as checking to see if the receiver is an enumerator. Do you know if that's the case?

Comment: I didn't check the implementation, but it seems much simpler for `Enumerable` to just call `each` no matter what.